# useEffect infinite loop issue with default prop value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a dropdown component; important part of it here:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"

type PropsType = {
    options?: any[]
}

export const DropDown = (props: PropsType) => {

    const { options = [] } = props;

    const [query, setQuery] = useState('');

    const [filteredOptions, setFilteredOptions] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setFilteredOptions(()=>[]); // calculate the filtered options according to the options and query cahnges
    }, [query, options])

    return (
        <div>
            DropDown
        </div>
    )
}
```

As you see, I have an `options` property, that if you do not specify it, it would be an empty array.

This is the simple use case of this component:

```
<DropDown options={[]} />
```

But if you set `options` property to `undefined`:

```
<DropDown options={undefined} />
```

...you will get an infinite loop.

**It is important that I know how to solve the infinite loop by using `useRef`**

But there will be another problem after using `useRef`:

If you use `useRef` to solve the problem, if you change `options` value during the runtime, for example after calling an API and change the `options` state, in the dropdown component, the `useEffect` will not trigger.

What should I do to have a dynamic `options` without getting infinite loop when someone sets it to `undefined`?

What is going on under the hood?

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { DropDown } from "./dropdown";
function App() {
  const [options,setOptions] = useState<string[]>([]);
  useEffect(()=>{
    setOptions(()=>['a','b'])
  },[])
  return (
    <div>
      <DropDown options={options}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Remove this state., you don't need it `const [filteredOptions, setFilteredOptions] = useState([]);`

Comment: You could possibly have say `options.length === 0 ? null : options` expression as a dependency (instead of just `options`).

Comment: dear ivan, could you tell me how and where you find this answer ?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the problem here is that you have default value for options.
UseEffect triggers new render, on that render you get a new options (because empty array will have new link to memory each time its created, and its created on each render), that new options array trigger useEffect that cause a new render and it goes to infinite loop.

I think after understanding this, it would be easy for you to fix this. The easiest fix that should work (but I'm not sure) is to set Dropdown.defaultProps, so you would set options there instead of component itself.

Good luck!